# Weak convergence in $\mathcal{l}_p$ and coordinatewise convergence

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $x^n=(x^n_1, x^n_2,...)$ be  a bounded sequence in $\mathcal{l}_p$ for $1<p<\infty$ and such that $x^n_i$ converges to $x_i$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$.  I'm trying to prove that $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$ belongs to $\mathcal{l}_p$ and $x^n$ converges weakly to $x$.

Since $x_n$ is bounded in a reflexive space there exists a subsequence $x^{n_k}$ weakly convergent  to some $y\in \mathcal{l}_p$. Testing with $e^n=(e^n_i)_i$, $e^n_i=\delta_{n,i}$ i get that the subsequence converges indeed to $x$, so $x\in \mathcal{l}_p$.
I'm stuck for the second part. Since the dual of $\mathcal{l}_p$ is $\mathcal{l}_q$ I'm trying to show that for evry $z\in\mathcal{l}_q$ , $z(x^n)-z(x)=\sum_iz_i(x^n_i-x_i)$ converges to zero.
$$
|z(x^n)-z(x)|\leq \sum_i|z_i(x^n_i-x^{n_k}_i)|+\left|\sum_iz_i(x^{n_k}_i-x_i)\right|.
$$
The second term goes to zero, but i don't know how to estimate the first sum.I don't know if this is the wrong approach, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part, we can actually write 
$$\sum_{j=1}^N|x_j|^p=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^N|x_j^n|^p\leqslant \sup_l\lVert x^l\rVert_p^p.$$

As $N$ is arbitrary, we get that $x$ belongs to $\ell^p$.

For the second part, we approximate the element $z$ by the sequence whose $N$ first terms are the corresponding to $z$, and the other ones are $0$. Call this vector $z_N$. Then 
$$|z(x^n)-z(x)|\leqslant |z_N(x^n)-z_N(x)|+|(z-z_N)x^n|+|(z-z_N)x|.$$
Notice that $|(z-z_N)x^n|\leqslant \lVert z-z_N\rVert_q\lVert  x^n\rVert_p\leqslant \lVert z-z_N\rVert_q\sup_l\lVert  x^l\rVert_p$
and $|(z-z_N)x|\leqslant \lVert z-z_N\rVert_q\lVert  x\rVert_p$, hence 
$$|z(x^n)-z(x)|\leqslant |z_N(x^n)-z_N(x)|+2\lVert z-z_N\rVert_q\sup_l\lVert  x^l\rVert_p.$$
For a fixed $N$, the first terms goes to $0$ because of the coordinatewise convergence.

Comment: Thank you. So this should work also for $p=1$ i guess, but not for $p=\infty$ because its dual is not $\ell_1$?

Comment: Actually it does not work for $\ell^1$ because in this case weak convergence is equivalent to strong convergence.

Comment: Ok, but  which part of the proof fails? And what about $\ell_\infty$?

Comment: A linear functional on $\ell^1$ can be represented by an element of $\ell^\infty$, but not better, hence the approximation argument with $z_N$ does not work anymore.

Comment: Hi, I just have some trouble breaking the last line into small steps. What exactly is $|z_N(x^n)-z_N(x)|$? How does the definition of $z_N$ and that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_i^n=x_i$ tell us that the term goes to 0? Thanks!