# Is closed ball of $l^2$ also closed in the product topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

As a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, the set

$$
l^2:=\biggl\{x\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\;\bigg|\;\|x\|_{l^2}^2:=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2<\infty\biggr\}
$$

is not closed with respect to the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, given that the sequences $\{x^{(n)}\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset l^2$, defined by

$$
x^{(n)}_m=\begin{cases}1&m\le n,\\ 0&m>n.\end{cases}\qquad m=1,2,\cdots
$$

are convergent on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ (i.e., convergent pointwise), but the limit lies outside $l^2$. However, is the set

$$
B:=\biggl\{x\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\;\bigg|\;\|x\|_{l^2}^2=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2\le1\biggr\}
$$

closed in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$? I cannot prove it is closed, nor can I construct a counterexample. Any advice is highly appreciated.

**P.S.** I am providing some background and motivation, even though they are not directly related to my question.

The space $l^2$ is the reproducing kernel Hilbert space of the standard Gaussian measure $\gamma$ on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$. The measure$\gamma$ is the Borel probability distribution specified from the family of finite-dimensional marginal distributions $\mathrm{N}_m(0,I_m)$. The measure $\gamma$ is Borel because the Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N})$ coincides with the product $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{C}$ on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

In the second edition of Giné and Nickl's *Mathematical Foundations of Infinite-Dimensional Statistical Models* (2021), on page 32, the Gaussian isoperimetric inequality for the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ (Theorem 2.2.4) is stated as follows:

Let $A$ be a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and $B$ the closed unit ball about zero of $l^2$. Then, for all $\epsilon>0$,

$$
\gamma(A+\epsilon B)\ge\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(\gamma(A))+\epsilon).
$$

I encountered this problem while trying to prove $A+\epsilon B$ is a Borel set.

Comment: $\ell^2$ is reflexive so that $B$ is weakly compact. Moreover, the inclusion $\ell^2\hookrightarrow \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is continuous for the weak topology of $\ell^2$ (and the product topology on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$). Hence, $B$ is compact in the product topology as a continuous image of a compact set.

Comment: @Jochen That reasoning is clear and exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No advanced results are needed
The set $B$ is the intersection of the sets $$B_N=\left \{x\in \ell^2\,:\, \sum_{n=1}^N|x_n|^2\le 1\right \}, \ N\in \mathbb{N}$$ which are closed in the product topology as the functions $x\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^N|x_n|^2$ are continuous in the product topology. Hence $B$ is closed in this topology as well.

Comment: That is a clean solution! It seems I was so absorbed in the functional analytic structures of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and $l^2$ that I overlooked it.

Answer (score 2):

It is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

On bounded sets in $l^2$, the weak topology and the topology of pointwise convergence coincide, so by Banach-Alaoglu, $B$ is compact under the topology of pointwise convergence. Since $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is Hausdorff, compactness ensures it is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: I was able to demonstrate what you suggested. except for the first statement: "On bounded sets in $l^2$, the weak topology and the topology of pointwise convergence coincide." I understand the former topology is equal to or stronger than the latter, but how can they actually be equivalent?

Comment: @Ano2Math5 The weak topology on $l^2$ is generated by seminorms of the form $u \mapsto |<v, u>|$ for $v \in l^2$. On bounded sets, you only need $v$ in a dense subset of $l^2$. Basically, suppose you know $<v, u_\lambda> \rightarrow <v, u>$ for $v \in S$ where $S \subseteq l^2$ is dense and suppose $u_\lambda, u$ all have norm bounded by 1. For any $v' \in l^2$, you can choose $v \in S$ with $||v' - v|| < \epsilon$. Then for $\lambda$ large enough s.t. $|<v, u_\lambda> - <v, u>| < \epsilon$, you have...

Comment: $|<v', u_\lambda> - <v', u>| \leq |<v, u_\lambda> - <v, u>| + |<v' - v, u_\lambda>| + |<v' - v, u>| < 3\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, this shows $u_\lambda \rightarrow u$ weakly. Now by linearity, the topology of pointwise convergence just corresponds to choosing $S$ to be $c_{00}$, finitely supported sequences in $l^2$, which is dense in $l^2$. (This only work when restricting to bounded sets. On the entire $l^2$, the two topologies are not equivalent.)

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012592/weak-convergence-in-mathcall-p-and-coordinatewise-convergence

Comment: I found a theorem stating that weak convergence is equivalent to (i) $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|x_n\|<\infty$ and (ii) $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$ for every $f$ from any strong dense subset $S$ of $X^*$ (on the page 121 of the 6th ed. of _Functional Analysis_ by Kôsaku Yosida). This theorem helped me understand what you said more deeply. Thank you both!

Comment: @DavidGao But I encountered a new problem. If the weak topology and the topology of pointwise convergence coincide on $B\subset l^2$, then we can conclude that they coincide on the entire $l^2$.

Comment: Here is the reasoning: Since both topologies are metrizable, we can deduce the equivalence of the topologies from the equivalence of converging sequences with respect to their respective topologies. A sequence that converges with respect to one topology is bounded with respect to the corresponding distance; therefore, we can apply the same reasoning above to conclude that it also converges with respect to the other topology.

Comment: @Ano2Math5 The first error here is that “bounded with respect to the corresponding distance” is not the same as bounded with respect to the $l^2$ norm. The sequence in your question description is a great counterexample, where the sequence converges in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ but is unbounded in $l^2$.

Comment: @Ano2Math5 The other error here is that the weak topology on $l^2$ is not metrizable. In a general, for a Banach space $X$, $X^*$ equipped with the weak$^*$ topology is metrizable iff $X$ is finite-dimensional. (The unit ball, or any norm-bounded set, for that matter, is actually metrizable if $X$ is separable. But you can’t really extend to the entire space.) So, as the weak topology is not metrizable (or more precisely, not first-countable), using sequences cannot fully describe the topology.

Comment: @Ano2Math5 Two additional remarks: an explicit example of sequence in $l^2$ that converges in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to something in $l^2$ but does not converge weakly can be given by $x_n = ne_n$, which converges to 0 in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. It does not converge weakly since, as mentioned in the reference you cited, a weakly converging sequence needs to be norm-bounded.

Comment: Also, the weak convergence implying norm-boundedness only works for sequences. An explicit example of a weakly converging net that is not uniformly norm-bounded can be constructed as follows: let $\Lambda$ be the directed index set of finite collections of vectors in $l^2$, ordered by inclusion. For each $\lambda \in \Lambda$, let $x_\lambda$ be any vector of norm $card(\Lambda)$ and orthogonal to all vectors in $\Lambda$, then $x_\lambda$ converges weakly to 0 but its norm diverges to infinity.

Comment: @DavidGao I've resolved the matter. Given that $l^2$ is separable, $B$ is metrizable with respect to the weak topology. Consequently, these two topologies coincide on $B$, but not on the entire $l^2$. When considering a general sequence in $l^2$ that converges pointwise, it is not necessarily $l^2$-bounded and cannot be considered as a sequence within $rB$ for any $r>0$. Thus, we cannot use the same reasoning and conclude that the sequence also converges in the weak topology.

Comment: @DavidGao I've learned a lot from you. I really appreciate it!